# Set a value on li using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can we set a `value` attribute inside a `<li></li>` element using jQuery/JavaScript?

I have set `innerHTML` inside an element but I don't know how to set a `value` on it without set value like `<li value="1"></li>`

```
<li></li>

<script>
  document.getElementById("area1").innerHTML = "1";
</script>
```

I want to set a value from jQuery as like above `innerHTML` given not from HTML tag.

Comment: Only `input` and `textarea` can have `value` IIRC...

Comment: `li` doesn't have a value attribute if you want to save id or something use `data-value` attribute

Comment: You can set a `data-value` attribute, which would likely be more correct for whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @JackBashford what about `button`, `select` etc etc?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan seems like while we were sleeping they reintroduced `value` in HTML5 for LI elements inside OL https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#Attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("li").attr("value",1); // set the attribute and value

alert($("li").attr("value")); // show the value
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
   <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @roko he was answering the OPs question

Comment: Just FYI as the `li` element does support the `value` attribute (thanks for pointing it out @RokoCBuljan) you can use `val()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 1):

As said, it doesn't have a lot of standard functions but you can do it like this.

```js
$('li')[0].setAttribute('value',1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li></li>
```

It would be better though if you use a **data** attribute.

```js
$('li')[0].setAttribute('data-value',1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `value` inside an `li` - you can use `data-value` instead:

```js
$("li").data("value", 1);
console.log($("li").data("value"));
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Also note you need a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element.

Comment: OK @RokoC.Buljan I'll just add one - thanks for that, I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

jquery is simple,
Just give id to `li`

```js
$('#area1').attr('area', '1')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <li id="area1">Hello LI </li>
</div>
```

have a look to code and let me know, if i can help you

Comment: FYI `<li>` is only allowed inside `<ul>`, `<ol>`, `<menu>`.

Comment: Note that this sets the inner text of the `li`, it's not adding a `value` attribute as the question is asking for